# Stripe - Creating new card for customers

Tags: django, stripe-payments

I'm trying to create a card for customers in these steps:

**1. Retrive Customer**

```
customer = stripe.Customer.retrieve(user_stripe)
```

**2. Token**

```
token = request.POST['stripeToken']
```

**3. Create a new card**

```
card = customer.Cards.create(card=token)
```

I'm having a problem with step-3. Seems like 'Cards' is backdated. I also tried

```
card = customer.sources.create(card=token)
```

from some other StackOverflow similar question. But 'sources' are also backdated I think. Now I'm stuck in the middle of a project. Please help me with this.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "backdated"?  Are you getting an error when you try the code in step 3?

Comment: well, I meant this syntax has been removed from Stripe, so I get errors when I try to write like this.

Comment: Code like this is depreciated, but it should still work fine. [The documentation is still available](https://stripe.com/docs/saving-cards) as well. What errors are you getting?

Comment: It says 'Attribute error: Cards is undefined'

Comment: Have you tried [the syntax shown in the Stripe API reference](https://stripe.com/docs/api/cards/create)? `stripe.Customer.create_source("cus_123", source="tok_123",)` for example?